# Azure Functions keys when hosted in AKS

Tags: kubernetes, azure-functions, manifest, azure-aks

I have a working Azure Function project running as a regular Azure Function App in Azure today.
Now i'm trying to move the function project to Azure Kubernetes Service.

I would like to add function key to a specific HttpTrigger, but haven't gotten it to work.

I have tryed to add the keys in my manifest file and called the specific HttpTrigger with the header: x-functions-key and the specific key.

```
data:
  host.master: {key}
  host.function.default: {key}
  host.systemKey.default: {key}
  functions.funcname.default: {key}
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {name}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
etc
etc
```

But no luck yet.
Any help what i need to do would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Create a Kubernetes secret to store your function key. kubectl create secret generic function-key --from-literal=key={function key}
Update your function deployment to reference the function key secret.
Update your HttpTrigger to require authorization and call the HttpTrigger using the x-functions-key header and the specific key.